# Can I load a .csv into Simplegeo Storage?

Tags: json, google-maps, geolocation, gis, simplegeo

Is there a straightforward way to load a .csv file into Simplegeo Storage? I don't have great coding skills and I'm trying to get things set up so I can ask a freelancer to create some maps for my app. If someone has existing code to do this I can probably figure out how to make it work for my situation.

Comment: you forgot to mention which language you're trying to accomplish this in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just skimmed over the api. Here's a basic example in python

Assumed csv format:

```
layer, id, lat, lon
```

python

```
from simplegeo.models import Record, Client

lines = open('file.csv').split('\n')
client = Client('your-oauth-token', 'your-oauth-secret')

for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(',')
    if len(parts) == 4:
        layer = parts[0].strip()
        id = parts[1].strip()
        lat = float(parts[2].strip())
        lon = float(parts[3].strip())
        r = Record(layer, id, lat, lon)
        client.storage.add_record(r)
```

After a bit more digging, I found a python example on their site for this exact purpose
https://simplegeo.com/docs/tutorials/general-hackery#how-import-csv-file-simplegeo

```
import csv
import simplegeo

OAUTH_TOKEN = '[insert_oauth_token_here]'
OAUTH_SECRET = '[insert_oauth_secret_here]'
CSV_FILE = '[insert_csv_file_here]'
LAYER = '[insert_layer_name_here]'

client = simplegeo.Client(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET)

def insert(data):
    layer = LAYER
    id=data.pop("id")
    lat=data.pop("latitude")
    lon=data.pop("longitude")
    # Grab more columns if you wish
    record = simplegeo.Record(layer,id,lat,lon,**data)
    client.add_record(record)

r = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_FILE, mode='U'))
for l in r:
    insert(l)
```